# Android can't change height of constraint layout in post

Tags: android, kotlin, layout

I am trying to change the height of the `ContraintLayout` inside the `post` block.

like so:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        changeHeight()
    }

    private fun changeHeight() {
        val layoutView = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.block1)
        layoutView.post {
            Log.d("222", "1===========")
            layoutView.run {
                Log.d("222", "2===========")
                layoutParams.height = 1000
                setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
            }
            Log.d("222", "3===========")
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work at all.
And the logs are printed out and the color was changed too.

If it removed the `layoutView.post` then it works.

I want to figure out why this happened, anyone knows? thanks!

I tried to move the `changeHeight()` into a button listener to see if the view isn't attached or something relative view. But still the same.

Comment: Setting a `LayoutParams` field like that will not cause a UI refresh (invalidation). When you were setting it directly in `onCreate()`, the value was being updated before the `Activity`'s first layout pass, so it had the new value for the initial layout. The `post()`, on the other hand, is causing that `LayoutParams` setting to be queued at the end of the initial UI work, but everything's been laid out already, so it seems like nothing's happened. If you add `layoutView.requestLayout()` at the end of the `post()` block, it should work as you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I tried `forceLayout()` yesterday, not realized the difference between it and`requestLayout()`.